# Use response.getWriter() to print JSTL tags

Tags: java, jstl

I made a jsp page and I used respose.getWriter() in order to print jstl tags -no particular reason I did this!Pure curiosity! :) - and I got a blank page. Does printWriter escpases xml or something? This is how jsp looks like:

```
<%-- 
    Document   : test
    Created on : Dec 8, 2011, 8:45:10 PM
    Author     : master
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%
response.getWriter().print("<c:set var=\"myValue\" value=\"a tag </tag>\" />");        
response.getWriter().print("<c:out value=\"${myValue}\" />");        
%>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSP tags are transformed into Java code by the JSP compiler, before any of your code runs.

`response.getWriter()` writes directly to the HTTP response and doesn't process any JSP.
You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

`getWriter()` writes into HTTP stream, while JSTL tag are processes and methods in servlet. You can't "write" jstl tags.